# Measurement of single qubit operator $U$ which is both Hermitian and unitary with eigenvalues $±1$

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

> Suppose we have a single qubit operator $U$ with eigenvalues $±1$, so that $U$ is both Hermitian and unitary, so it can be regarded both as an observable and a quantum gate. Suppose we wish to measure the observable $U$. That is, we desire to obtain a measurement result indicating one of the two eigenvalues, and leaving a post-measurement state which is the corresponding eigenvector. How can this be implemented by a quantum circuit? Show that the following circuit implements a measurement of $U$:

[image: qc]

**Ref. to Exercise 4.34 in QC and QI by Nelsen and Chuang**

$$
|\psi_0\rangle =|0\rangle\otimes|\psi_{in}\rangle\\
|\psi_1\rangle =\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\psi_{in}\rangle\\
|\psi_2\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[|0\rangle\otimes |\psi_{in}\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes U|\psi_{in}\rangle]\\
|\psi_3\rangle=\frac{1}{2}[|0\rangle\otimes(I+U)|\psi_{in}\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes(I-U)|\psi_{in}\rangle]
$$
Note that,

$U(I+U)|\psi_{in}\rangle=(U+U^2)|\psi_{in}\rangle=(U+I)|\psi_{in}\rangle=1(I+U)|\psi_{in}\rangle$ and $U(I-U)|\psi_{in}\rangle=-1(I-U)|\psi_{in}\rangle$

$\implies (I+U)|\psi_{in}\rangle$ and $(I-U)|\psi_{in}\rangle$ are eigenvectors of the operator $U$ with corresponding eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$, respectively.

And by projecting the first qubit the second qubit is projected to either $(I+U)|\psi_{in}\rangle$ or $(I-U)|\psi_{in}\rangle$, therefore this circuit implements a measurement of $U$.

---

It is proved that projective measurements together with unitary dynamics are sufficient to implement a general measurement, by introducing an ancilla system having an orthonormal basis $|m\rangle$ in one-to-one correspondence with the possible outcomes of the measurement we wish to implement.

Please check [Page 94, QC and QI by Nelsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) for the proof of this statement.

Are we using this statement to implement the circuit above ?

---

Can't we have a circuit like : [image: qc2]

with $U'=\sum |m \rangle\langle\psi_m |=|0\rangle\langle \psi|(I+U)+|1\rangle\langle \psi|(I-U)$ where $|\psi_i\rangle$ are the eigenvectors of the operator $U$ ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem with using the circuit $U|\psi\rangle$ is that upon measuring you destroy the state in the sense that you get the outcome $m$ but you don't obtain a state left in the eigenvector of $U$. The first circuit you mentioned does achieve this.

Comment: @Condo That makes sense. How about its connection with the statement in the middle section of my post where I mentioned about introducing an ancilla system to equate a general measurement with a unitary dynamics together with a projective measurement ?

Comment: I don't think you need the statements about *general measurements $\equiv$ unitary dynamics +  projective measurements* is used/needed to explain the first circuit you discuss. Where do you think there would be any sort of *general measurement*?

Comment: @Condo Thanks I think your first comment gives the reasoning, though it could be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the statements about *general measurements ≡ unitary dynamics + projective measurements* as it's not used/needed to explain the first circuit you discuss.

If I understand correctly, the problem with using the circuit $U|ψ⟩$ is that upon measuring you destroy the state in the sense that you get the outcome $m$ but you don't obtain a state left in the eigenvector of $U$. The first circuit you mentioned does achieve this.